# form submit not working

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a table that prints out all available cameras. It uses a form to change these settings. The problem is that the form only updates the last camera in the entry.  In other words if I change the form and hit "Apply" for the last camera in the list it will work.  If I change the form for any other camera in this list it changes the one to have the same settings as the last camera in the list. There are no issues with any values as far as I can tell.

Sorry for the long dump here, but without being able to narrow down the problem I thought I should include the bulk of it:

```
// Dont allow direct linking
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
//get current user
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
// get a reference to the database
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();

$query_camera_name = "SELECT camera_id, camera_name, camera_status, camera_quality, camera_hash, camera_type FROM #__cameras WHERE user_id=".$user->id." AND camera_status!='DELETED'";
$db->setQuery($query_camera_name);
//get number of cameras so we can build the table accordingly
$db->query();
$num_rows = $db->getNumRows();
// We can use array names with loadAssocList.
$result_cameras = $db->loadAssocList();


if (isset($_POST['apply_changes'])) {

    //process changes to camera options     
    $camera_id = $_POST['camera_id'];
    $camera_status = check_input($_POST['camera_status']);
    $camera_name = check_input($_POST['camera_name'], "You entered an empty camera name. Enter another name and apply changes.");
    $camera_quality = check_input($_POST['camera_quality']);

    $query_insert_camera = 'UPDATE `#__cameras` SET `camera_status` ="'.$camera_status.'", `camera_name` ="'.$camera_name.'", `camera_quality` ="'.$camera_quality.'" WHERE `camera_id`='.$camera_id;
    $db->setQuery($query_insert_camera);
    $db->query();
    header("location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}

echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";


<link href="dashboard/webcam_widget.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function oncameraSubmit(camera_id)
{
    document.active_cameras.camera_id.value = camera_id;
    return confirm('Apply changes?');
}


</script>
<?php


echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";


if (!isset($result_cameras))
{
   //TODO 
}
else 
{

    if ($num_rows == 0)
    {           
        echo '<b><i><center>You currently have no cameras setup.  Add a Camera below.</center></i></b>';
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <form name="active_cameras" action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="camera_id" value="" />
        <table id="webcam-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Camera Type</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Quality</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Camera Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
        for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
        {

            //camera_status
            if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_status"] == "ENABLED")
            {
                $enabled_option =  "value='ENABLED' selected='selected'"; 
                $disabled_option = "value='DISABLED'";
            }
            else
            {
                $enabled_option =  "value='ENABLED'";
                $disabled_option = "value='DISABLED' selected='selected'";
            }

            //camera_quality
            if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_quality"] == "HIGH")
            {
                $high_option =  "value='HIGH' selected='selected'"; 
                $medium_option = "value='MEDIUM'";
                $mobile_option =  "value='MOBILE'";
            }
            else if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_quality"] == "MEDIUM")
            {
                $high_option =  "value='HIGH'";
                $medium_option = "value='MEDIUM' selected='selected'";
                $mobile_option =  "value='MOBILE'";
            }
            else if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_quality"] == "MOBILE")
            {
                $high_option =  "value='HIGH'";
                $medium_option = "value='MEDIUM'";
                $mobile_option =  "value='MOBILE' selected='selected'";
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO proper logging
            }

            //camera_type
            if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_type"] == "WEBCAM")
            {
                $webcam =  "value='WEBCAM' selected='selected'"; 
                $axis = "value='AXIS'";
                $other =  "value='IPCAM'";
            }
            else if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_type"] == "AXIS")
            {
                $webcam =  "value='WEBCAM'";
                $axis = "value='AXIS' selected='selected'";
                $other =  "value='IPCAM'";
            }
            else if ($result_cameras[$i]["camera_type"] == "IPCAM")
            {
                $webcam =  "value='WEBCAM'";
                $axis = "value='AXIS'";
                $other =  "value='IPCAM' selected='selected'";
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO 
            }

?>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="camera_type">
                    <option <?php echo $webcam; ?>>Webcam</option>
                    <option <?php echo $axis; ?>>AXIS</option>
                    <option <?php echo $other; ?>>Other</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" size="32" maxlength="64" name="camera_name" value="<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="camera_quality">
                    <option <?php echo $high_option; ?>>High</option>
                    <option <?php echo $medium_option; ?>>Medium</option>
                    <option <?php echo $mobile_option; ?>>Mobile</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="camera_status">
                    <option <?php echo $enabled_option; ?>>Enabled</option>
                    <option <?php echo $disabled_option; ?>>Disabled</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="apply_changes" value="Apply" onClick="javascript:return oncameraSubmit(<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_id"]; ?>);"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple HTML elements with the same name. As such, you want to get back an array of values when the form is posted.

As such, [Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes/4997271#4997271) looks like it might be helpful.

Alternatively, extend oncameraSubmit so that it stores all the data in a hidden input field (not just the id). Then when you update the database, use these hidden fields.

Comment: The easiest way would be to issue x update queries where x is the number of array elements. Alternatively, see my last paragraph - if you do it that way, you can issue only a single update.

Answer (score 0):

Your form element names are clashing. When you define a form element e.g. 'camera_status' twice, you will only receive the last value in the POST.

Use form array notation, e.g.: "camera_status[]" or even better "camera_status[$id]". Then your PHP code will recieve arrays as POST data and you will be able to update everything at once.