# Array limited to 1,001 keys when non-sequential keys used

Tags: php, arrays

I pull two IDs from a database via a query. One is the table's unique primary key (`temp_id`), and one is not (`auto_id`). The query gives me 1,477 records.

When I add these to an array like so, and then `var_dump()` the array, I get the full 1,477:

`<input type="checkbox" name="temp_id[]" value="<?=$auto_id?>">`

However when I use this code, suddenly the array only contains 1,001:

`<input type="checkbox" name="temp_id[<?=$temp_id?>]" value="<?=$auto_id?>">`

Is there any inherent reason for this? As far as I can tell, because `$temp_id` is unique, this should not cause any "clashes" in the data, or overwritten keys.

**FORM CODE:**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['date']) || !filter_var($_GET['date'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    header("Location: ./");
    exit();
}
$date = $_GET['date'];
$upload_date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
require_once("db.php");

$automatch_query = mysql_query("SELECT temp_id, auto_id FROM advertisers INNER JOIN update_tempdata ON advertisers.advertiser_id = update_tempdata.auto_id WHERE auto_id > 0 AND upload_date = '$upload_date' ORDER BY advertiser_name");
?>
<form action="match-auto-script.php" method="post">
    <?php
    while ($automatch_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($automatch_query)) {
        extract($automatch_data);
        ?>
        <input class="toggleable" type="checkbox" name="temp_id[<?=$temp_id?>]" value="<?=$auto_id?>" checked>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
<pre><?php var_dump($_POST); ?></pre>
```

Comment: Can you share your full code please?

Comment: I can try, but it's a big script. Let me edit the useful parts in to the code.

Comment: Are you sure `$temp_id` is unique? Try to do `array_unique()` and see if you still have 1,477 elements in array.

Comment: Maybe the browser only allows 1,001 form elements? Whereas the first example is the same element but as an array so its only 1 element with 1,477 entries.

Comment: Do you have something like suhosin installed? It might limit your array sizes.

Comment: 100% all unique. No Suhosin. Have set `ini_set("max_input_vars", "10000");` on both the form page, and the script page. No luck.

Comment: This can happen if your `update_tempdata` contains multiple records for the same `auto_id`. What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM advertisers` tell you?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple `temp_id`s with the same `auto_id`. Is there any way around this? I thought if the keys were unique...

Comment: However if this is the case, would I not get 1,001 records with a sequential integer key, too?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with sequential/non-sequential keys. It's all due to the way you're naming your input elements. See [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4997252/1233508), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8109074/1233508) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to [@DCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233508/dcoder)'s links to answers in other threads, I use the following solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="temp_id[][<?=$temp_id?>]" value="<?=$auto_id?>" checked>
```

This gives me all 1,477 records as their *own* array, but at least I have crucial links between each unique `temp_id` and non-unique `auto_id`.

Comment: `name="temp_id[<?=$temp_id?>][]"` would be a better option.