# Cannot checkbox values as array from $_POST?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes)

I'm a little new to web development and this is a problem (having completely stumped me) I feel has a simple solution, so I won't beat around the bush trying to figure it out myself. I will also focus on the most important bits.

I have some PHP code that is outputting a table, a form and a checkbox next to each row. Each one of the checkboxes looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data_id" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="data_id" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="data_id" value="3">
```

As well as the submit button:

```
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'/>
```

Standard form setup, nothing special.

I'd like to get the checked items in an array, however when I retrieve the data from the form using $_POST:

```
if($_POST['data_id'])
    {
        var_dump($_POST['data_id']); //returns string
        print_r($_POST['data_id']); //shows only one checkbox value
    };
```

What exactly am I doing wrong that the variable is not being returned an array?

Comment: How should I then call the var in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's form-to-array syntax requires `[]` in the element name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data_id[]" value="1">
                                    ^^
```

Comment: Fair does, but when I call $_POST['data_id'] I'm once again given a string? How should I call it in PHP correctly?

Comment: it should come out as an array. do a `var_dump($_POST['data_id'])`.

Comment: did you make sure to add the `[]` to your form field names and to reload the form?

Comment: My bad, hadn't reloaded the form. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When PHP parses data to `$_POST/GET/REQUEST` it only presents the data as an array if the field name ends in `[]` or `[some_index]` (otherwise it drops all but one of the values).

Rename the fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data_id[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="data_id[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="data_id[]" value="3">
```

… or get [the raw post data](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) and parase it yourself. (I don't recommend this latter approach).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data_id[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="data_id[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="data_id[]" value="3">
```