# Laravel 4 Form Validation, Extending the __call() method

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I want to extend the Form validation class to support array form elements like described [here for L3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14199205/570763) in L4.

First, I changed the Validator alias with this in my `app/config/app.php`:

```
'Validator'       => 'app\lib\Support\Facades\Validator',
```

Then , I saved these codes as app/lib/Support/Facades/Validator.php

```
<?php namespace app\lib\Support\Facades;


class Validator extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator {

    public function __call($method, $parameters) {

      if (substr($method, -6) === '_array') {

          $method = substr($method, 0, -6);
          $values = $parameters[1];
          $success = true;
          foreach ($values as $value) {
              $parameters[1] = $value;


              $rule = snake_case(substr($method, 8));

                if (isset($this->extensions[$rule]))
                {
                    $success &= $this->callExtension($rule, $parameters);
                }

                throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist.");
          }
          return $success;
      } else {
          return parent::__call($method, $parameters);
      }

    }

    protected function getMessage($attribute, $rule) {

        if (substr($rule, -6) === '_array') {
          $rule = substr($rule, 0, -6);
        }

        return parent::getMessage($attribute, $rule);
    }

}
```

Then I made sure my `composer.json` has the folder included for autoload:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",

        "app/lib",
        "app/lib/Support",
        "app/lib/Support/Facades"
    ]
},
```

Then, I ran `php composer.phar dump-autoload` to generate autoload classes.

The thing is that, it seems like this isn't working. I even tried to add a custom validation method into the file I've generated, something like this:

```
protected function validateTest($attribute, $value) {
    return $value=='test';
}
```

It says: `Method [validateTest] does not exist.`. I altered the `protected` to `public`, still same.

`get_class(Validator::getFacadeRoot())` gives me `\Illuminate\Validation\Factory`, but when I extend the class I've written to it, I get this error: `Non-static method Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() should not be called statically`.

**Note**: Yes, I didn't extend the rules like L4 way, because I don't want to add a new rule, but I want to change the method `__call()`'s and `getMessage()`'s behaviour.

What am I missing, how can I make this work?

Comment: Did you look @ this SO answer for L4? http://stackoverflow.com/q/18161785/1317935

Comment: @TheShiftExchange How did I miss this?! Thanks, that worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I didn't search enough. As suggested in the comments, I just added the codes shared [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18163546/570763) to my `app/routes.php` without creating a new file or changing the alias, and it worked flawlessly!

This is the validation rule that I've given with the solution:

```
$rules = array(
    'items'     => 'required|min:1|integerOrArray'
);
```