# Validate input file image array in laravel 4

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have a form like this that can have multiples images[] field:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'files' => true)) }}
    <input type="file" name="images[]">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

How can I validate this field with laravel 4 validation?
I tried this rule but it didn't work:

```
$rules = array('images[]' => 'required|image');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$rules = array(
    'images'     => 'required|min:1|integerOrArray'
);
```

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18894578/385402)

Use the validator from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18163546/385402)

Comment: Didn't work. Method [validateIntegerOrArray] does not exist.
I guess I will have to extend the validation class or make my own rule.

Comment: Yes, use the validator extended in the question of the link I provided. See my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all are you running "images[]" over a loop? There is plenty of code examples for laravel 4 that actually don't work at all... And people who wrote them don't know how to use var_dump()...

If not - your probably running validation over a array of objects, try check:

```
var_dump(Input::file('files'));
```

So now after this lecture, lets run a for loop (had some issue with foreach idk why):

```
$files = Input::file('images');
$filesCount = count($files);

for ($i=0; $i < $filesCount; $i++)
{
    $file = $files[$i];
    $input = array(
        'upload' => $files[$i]
    );

    $rules = array(
        'upload' => 'image|max:15500'
    );
    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);
}
```

And now you can run your validation. Laravel4 only tries to valid mime type... so its vulnerable.

Comment: I thought there was a rule that would do that to me, apparently there is not. I do not like the idea or run the validation on loop. Like I commented, it seems the only way is to either extend the validation class or write my own rule. Thanks for your answer.