# Salesforce/Apex - Saving values of dynamic number of checkboxes

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I currently have a Visualforce page embedded on the contact record that displays all active campaigns with a chexckbox indicating if the contact is a member of the campaign (if checked then the contact is a member). I also have a command button to save changes. The visualforce code is generated using an **apex:repeat** like as so:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!campaignWrappers}" var="cm">
  <div class="MailingRow">
     <apex:outputText styleClass="CampaignLabel" value="{!cm.c.Name}" ></apex:outputText>
     <apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="CampaignCheck" value="{!cm.selected}" />
  </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

My question is, what is the best way to go about passing the checkbox values to the controller? Ideally I would like to pass across only checkboxes that have been changed, passing across a list of those that have been gone from checked to unchecked and a second list that contains the checkboxes that have gone from unchecked to checked. I can then insert and delete these lists.

Is this a case where an actionSupport tag should be used on the checkbox?

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onChange" action="{!updateChangeList}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whole collection will be sent back to the server (so state of all checkboxes). That's not too different between Salesforce and any other web-related language (see [Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes) for example. Main difference is that usually you'd use a variable with name ending in `[]` and SF will use unique names with incrementing number somewhere in the name).

If you really want to build 2 lists - maybe some javascript magic of adding/removing content of 2 hidden text fields... but that's bit messy.

When the form will be submitted and your `updateChangeList()` gets called you could iterate the collection of CampaignWrappers and compare with previous value. Either store the previous value in 1 more variable in the wrapper & not expose it to the user or you'll still know based on what was in the Campaign:

```
Set<Id> campaignsToBeAddedTo = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> campaignsToBeRemovedFrom = new Set<Id>();

for(CampaignMember cm : campaignWrappers){
   if(cm.selected && cm.c.CampaignMembers.isEmpty(){
      // is ticket but wasn't a member before
      campaignsToBeAddedTo.add(cm.c.Id);
   } else if (!cm.selected && !cm.c.CampaignMembers.isEmpty()){
      // not ticked but used to be a member
      campaignsToBeRemovedFrom.add(cm.c.Id);
   }
}
```

You could even optimize it a bit (like put isEmpty() checks to helper variable). Or read about setter methods that can have "side effects". After all a loop like that will be run for you anyway when form data will be deserialized. http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2008/06/property-access.html is a nice starting point (it's ancient, I know. Basically before this blog post we had to write `Boolean getSelected()` and `void setSelected(Boolan b)` for each variable we wanted to use in VF).

last but not least - a link to [page execution order](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_lifecycle.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the info eyescream. I'm slightly confused. So using actionSupport on each checkbox is not the way forward, instead I would have an action on my commandbutton which does the logic as per your exampel above. Would I need to set an ID for each checkbox so that I can identify them in the controller? I'm unable to set the ID in visualforce like so: id={!cm.c.id} as it must be a literal?

Comment: ActionSupport is not a magic wand ;) It's a AJAX shortcut to have whole form submitted & action executed. Treat it as immediate clicking on some hidden button the moment user selects a checkbox. The point is it'll be a network traffic. If you want to send them one by one - sure, go for it. You can but don't have to set Ids. They'll get `id` and `name` set automatically. Just don't worry, assume that when method body is entered all variables will be parsed etc. for you, ready to use

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation eyescream!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Wrapper class for contact object to store the current and new status of the contact to check whether the contact is member of campaign.

```
public class ContactWrapper 
{                 
 public Boolean checked{ get; set; }            
 public Contact con { get; set;}                     

 public AccountSKUWrapper()
 {                
   con = new Contact();                
   checked = false;            
 }                     

 public ContactWrapper(Contact c)
 {                
   con= c;                
   checked = c.selected;            
 }
```

}

Using **selected** field we can identify whether contact is a member of Campaign and **checked** variable in the wrapper helps in identifying what input given in the VF page. Create the list of ContactWrapper and initialize each ContactWrapper object using Overloaded Contructor "ContactWrapper(Contact c)".

```
    <apex:repeat value="<ContactWrapper Object>" var="cm">
  <div class="MailingRow">
     <apex:outputText styleClass="CampaignLabel" value="{!cm.con.Name}" ></apex:outputText>
     <apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="CampaignCheck" value="{!cm.checked}" />
  </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

During save button click, follow below steps: Check the value of checked variable differing from selected field.

```
Create 2 list **CHANGEDCONTACTLIST** and **UNCHANGEDCONTACTLIST** and then Loop through the list of ContactWrapper

begin loop
1.If checked differs then load **CHANGEDCONTACTLIST** with Contact Wrapper object as this need to be updated in Contact object; in order to update selected field of contact. 

2.Else load **UNCHANGEDCONTACTLIST**.
end loop
```

Eventually using these two list  **CHANGEDCONTACTLIST** and **UNCHANGEDCONTACTLIST**. you can do insert or delete dml.

I believe there is no use of ActionSupport tag here as all the values required will be used (read/write) using getter and setter of the ContactWrapper list.

```
public List<ContactWrapper> wrapper {get;set;}
```