# Table with checkbox: send mail to those checked

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I have a database tabe:

```
ID    email
```

I call this data from the database and post it on a `html table`:

```
<?php
  $sql = $link->query("SELECT ...");
  while($data = $sql->fetch_object){
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <?=$data->ID?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?=$data->email?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="mail_<?=$data->ID?>">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<?php
  }
?>

<input type="button" id="send_mail_button">
```

The last column has a checkbox. If this chechbox is checked, when I click on `send_mail_button`, I'd like to send a mail to **every email where the checkbox is checked**: to me it's the same if this will be done with an `AJAX` call either with a `form post`.

I'm able to do this with:

```
$subject = 'something';
$body = 'hello world!';

foreach($to as $t){
    mail($t, $subject, $body);
}
```

but I'm not able to create an array (`$to`) with all the `email` address and then retrive every email with a `foreach` loop where I send the mails.

How can I do it?

Comment: Using an array would work.  Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

I might be a ways off with this answer (I haven't used checkboxes for a long long time), but I am pretty sure that you need to use the `name='zzzz'` (not id) in the checkbox entry, and secondly, you will need to enter a value for it.

Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="something" name="ids[]" value="<?php=$data->email?>">
```

then in your php code you can do something along the lines of:

```
foreach ($_POST['ids'] as $thisID)
{
    // you now do what you need to do using the ID
}
```

This is because checkboxes are actually an array, and you can step through each one individually using the foreach statement.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible using AJAX?

Comment: It probably is, but I haven't done anything with AJAX, so I am unable to answer further :(

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="emails[]" value="mail_<?=$data->ID?>">

foreach($_POST['emails'] as $email)
{
    $getid = explode('_', $email);
    $email_id = $getid[1];
    // dsth
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible using AJAX?

Comment: Of course, just using SEND to another script via AJAX but I am not very goof friend with AJAX :D

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mail[]" value="<?=$data->email?>">
```

And then in your forearch do this:

```
foreach($_POST['to'] as $t){
    mail($t, $subject, $body);
}
```

On a sidenote, when used on a public envoirement this is bad practice since it does not do any checks and enables users to inject e-mail addresses in your script.

An alternate solution would be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mail[]" id="<?=$data->ID?>">
```

Then, after submission run another query to retrieve all related e-mail adresses:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM emails WHERE ID IN (".mysql_real_escape_string(implode(",",$_POST['mail'])).")";
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible using AJAX?

Comment: Ofcourse, if you use jQuery you could use $.post(); and the $.serialize() function on the form object for the post data parameter.