# How to add checkbox data and text to database by form (php)?

Tags: php, database, forms, checkbox, insert

I have a database with 3. The first tables are named "periorismoi" and "programmata". The first one has 2 colums ("Auxon" , "Title") and the second one 3 ("Auxon" , "Name" , "Periorismoi"). I made a page with a form of adding a new 'programmata'. In the column "Name" a text will be added from the form and in the column "Periorismoi" a name will be added from a checkbox (from the same form).  The checkbox names will derive from the table "periorismoi". I am giving you the page of the form and then the Insert to the database (action) page.  It doesn't work. Maybe a server error ? It used to work before I put the checkboxes in the form. Note that Periorismoi is different than periorismoi.

```
   <form action='Insert.php' method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' periorismoi="periorismoi">
   <textarea name="title" placeholder="Πρόγραμμα" rows=\"1\" cols=\"50\"></textarea>
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'student1905','123456');
mysql_select_db('student1905');
$q="select * FROM periorismoi";
$result=mysql_query($q);
$counts=mysql_num_rows($result);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $counts; ++$i ) {
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    if(isset($row[ "Title" ]))
   {$Title= $row[ "Title" ];
     }
    ?> 
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo "periorismoi$i"; ?>" value=""<?php echo $row['Title']; ?>""><?php echo "$Title";?>      <br>      
<?php
}
?>
```

Insert.php page:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'student1905','123456');
mysql_select_db('student1905');
$title= trim($_POST["title"]);
if(!$link) 
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
    if(strlen($title) == 0) 
    {
        header("Location:Index.php"); 
    }
    else
    {
     mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
      $periorismoi = implode(',', $_POST['periorismoi']);
    $len = sizeof($periorismoi);
    for($i=0; $i<$len;$i++){ 
        $sql="INSERT INTO programmata (Auxon,Title,Periorismoi) VALUES ('','$title','$periorismoi')";
                 mysql_query($sql);
    }
      header("Location:Index.php"); ; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: do you get any error message? besides that please pay attention to possible sql injection attacks in your code.

Comment: @TobiasZander No error shown. It worked before connecting the checkboxes to the table "periorismoi".

Comment: @TobiasZander How do i check sql injection attacks ? I mean how do I avoid them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form, you create multiple checkboxes with different name attributes:

```
(periorismoi0, periorismoi1, ...)
```

Then when you read your parameters you are trying to read `$_POST['periorismoi']` which doesn't exist. You should either read every single checkbox (`$_POST['periorismoi0'], $_POST['periorismoi1'], ...` (which I highly don't recommend) or you should define multiple checkboxes with the same name.

Check this thread: [Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes)

Comment: I wish I could give you reputation. You helped me so much.