# Entering multiple check box value into the database with php

Tags: php, html, database, checkbox, pdo

I'm trying to enter multiple check box value into the database, the thing is, only those checkbox value will be entered which are checked and im doing it with PDO, but it is just not inserting the value, here is my code-

**HTML**

```
<li><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1"     checked="checked"/>Accesories</li>
<li><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" checked="checked"/>Bags</li>
<li><input class="check"  type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" checked="checked"/>Caps & Hats</li>
<li><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="4" checked="checked"/>Hoodies & Sweatshirts</li>
```

**PHP**

```
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++)
{
    $insersql = "INSERT INTO user_branch(branch_id,user_id) SELECT :checkbox, user.user_id FROM user WHERE email=:email";
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare($insersql);
    $stmt->bindparam(":checkbox",$checkbox[$i]);
    $stmt->bindparam(":email",$email);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Check `$_POST['checkbox']` values - `var_dump` or `print_r`

Comment: If you haven't got `$email` set, it's not going to work - and I can't see it anywhere in the code provided.

Comment: Yes i set that in the code, i just posted the related code to check box

Comment: @user2845328 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes check the link

Comment: Take a look at this answer to find out what the error is when PDO fails - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/689579

Comment: `bindParam`? (note the capital *P*)