# php get label text of multiple checked checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox, foreach, label

This is an extended question from: [Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes)

I am trying to get the **labels** of each checked checkbox, then display it as such:

"Sales | Engineering"  (without the quotes)

Or if only one checkbox was selected:

"Sales"

HTML (myform.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form name='myform' method='post' action='result.php'>
<label for='sales'>Sales</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='sales' value='Sales' /><br/>

<label for='insideSales'>Inside Sales</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='insideSales' value='Inside Sales' /><br/>

<label for='engineering'>Engineering</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='engineering' value='Engineering' /><br/>

<label for='fieldService'>Field Service</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='fieldService' value='Field Service' /><br/>

<label for='production'>Production</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='production' value='Production' /><br/>

<label for='warehouse'>Warehouse</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='warehouse' value='Warehouse'/><br/>
<br/>
<input type='submit' id='subBtn' value='Submit'/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP (result.php):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
    <p><?php 
          if(!empty($_POST["loc_chks"]) and is_array($_POST["loc_chks"])) {
            echo implode(' | ',$_POST["loc_chks"]);
          } else { echo "we have a loser";}

        ?>
    </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

*Edited - the "if" statement in the php file always returns false even if multiple checkboxes are checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use array type naming loc_chks[], this also lets you use specific keys for each item, for example: `loc_chks[sales]` and with PHP you have it in `$_POST["loc_chks"]["sales"]` 
HTML (myform.html):

```
<label for='sales'>Sales</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='sales' value='Sales' /><br/>

<label for='insideSales'>Inside Sales</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='insideSales' value='Inside Sales' /><br/>

<label for='engineering'>Engineering</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='engineering' value='Engineering' /><br/>

<label for='fieldService'>Field Service</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='fieldService' value='Field Service' /><br/>

<label for='production'>Production</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='production' value='Production' /><br/>

<label for='warehouse'>Warehouse</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='warehouse' value='Warehouse' /><br/>
```

In PHP you can use `implode` funciton, which lets you concatenate array items with the glue string (as first parameter) 
PHP (result.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

 if(!empty($_POST["loc_chks"]) and is_array($_POST["loc_chks"])) {
     $loc = implode(' | ',$_POST["loc_chks"]);
 }

?>
```

Comment: For some reason this if statement is returning FALSE..I think it has something to do with my setup. I'm going to edit my original post to show the full files.

Answer (score 1):

Value is missing... use following

```
<label for='sales'>Sales</label>
 <input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='sales' value='Sales' /><br/>

 <label for='insideSales'>Inside Sales</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='insideSales' value='Inside Sales' /><br/>

<label for='engineering'>Engineering</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='engineering' value='Engineering' /><br/>

<label for='fieldService'>Field Service</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='fieldService' value='Field Service' /><br/>

<label for='production'>Production</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='production' value='Production' /><br/>

<label for='warehouse'>Warehouse</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='warehouse' value='Warehouse'/><br/>
```

Comment: This looks promising. Let me try it out.

Comment: What if the user only picked one? or what if the user picked three?

Answer (score 1):

First of all assign those labels as values of checkboxes and secondly name the checkboxes like an array. Without naming all your checkboxes like that, you won't get multiple values like you are expecting in your loop.

```
<label for='sales'>Sales</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='loc_chks[]' id='sales' value="Sales"/><br/>
                                     ^^             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - Im as dumb@$$. I didn't close out the "name" property in the form. Everything works - Thank you all for your input. George PHP has a slightly better solution.