# Non-checked radio is not POSTing its value

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, radio-button

Looking for solution how i can POST 2 of my radio button value when it checked or not.

my code is

```
<input name="r1" id="r1" type="radio">r1
<input name="r2" id="r2" type="radio">r2
```

when i submiting the form i want 2 params to be POSTed:
r1: value
r2: value

value = 1 (if selected)
but need to pass also 0 if not selected.

tryied to set the value on submit button onclick action, but it's not helps.

Comment: You can’t. Fix your server side.

Comment: Also fix your HTML, since you have two elements with the same `id` (this makes the HTML invalid).

Comment: my mistake in example code, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put:

You **can't**. Use checkboxes if you want to post two or more values.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="2">
```

Comment: With those `name`s, won't the value of the second over-write the value of the first on submission/receipt?

Comment: @Christian   yes, it's an option by in the end of the day i need that user will able to select only one option. should i try to play with onclick action to disable other checkbox when something selected? or maybe some other ways to make checkboxes act like radio?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Simply put: if you an user is only allowed to select one option, go with the radio, and if the user is allowed to select multiple options, use checkboxes. @user2988257

Comment: @DavidThomas Ah, forgot the `[]`.

Comment: @DavidThomas: No, they both get sent. `[]` is a PHP thing.

Comment: my server side expect 2 posts: r1: 0 r2: 1 or something like this

Comment: @minitech Sure about that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes

Comment: @user2988257 You've two choices — change how HTTP works, or change your serverside script to handle one value. I know which one I'd pick ;)

Comment: @Christian: Yes, note how that question is about PHP

Comment: ops.. tryied to implement this solution, i found it's good for some my different need (to pass empty params to next page) but still not good for what i was looking for. i think it should be done with js.. just looking for a way to do it with onclick action..

Comment: @user2988257 Preventing user from selecting more than one? Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You should have both `<input>`s be of different names and IDs and create a new radio for each "false" state; then bind a Javascript listener to the `onClick` event - using jQuery:

### Code

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" value="1"> R1
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1_2" value="0" style="display: none">
<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="1"> R2
<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2_2" value="0" style="display: none">
```

```js
$("#radio1").click(function() {
  $("#radio2").prop("checked", false);
  $("#radio2_2").prop("checked", true);
});
$("#radio2").click(function () {
  $("#radio1").prop("checked", false);
  $("#radio1_2").prop("checked", true);
});
```

### Explanation

You set each of the two radios a different name; thus, each pertains to a different group. You must have a different radio for the false-like value of each input (its style was set to hidden, since the two radio groups should look like they're a single one). There is a problem: **if you check one, the other won't be unchecked. Help!**

**But you want only one of them to be checked at a time**. The Javascript/jQuery function deals with that as follows:

- If **#radio1** is clicked (and thus checked), **#radio2** must be unchecked;
- It then checks the hidden button from the *radio2* group, that is, **#radio2_2**;
- The reverse happens if **#radio2** is clicked (**#radio1** is unchecked and **#radio1_2**, checked).

This is an elegant (albeit arguably hacky) solution to what you want to do. It could work if the hidden radios' types was `hidden` instead of `radio`, though I'm not sure how. Making them hidden radios makes it easy to handle them as GET/POST values.

Comment: Will also depend on the user having JavaScript enabled. Know it's a minority that don't, but still worth considering.

Comment: Of course, but this is the only solution filling the requirements without changing anything server-side.