# Checkbox with the same name POST

Tags: php, html, post, checkbox

apologies if this is simple, I am trying to grab the selections from multiple checkboxes. 
I have created multiple checkboxes which look as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="a" id="selection">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="b" id="selection">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="c" id="selection">
```

I then can have a button and retrieve the form data using codeigniters built in form helper:

```
$temp = $this->input->post('checkbox');
```

if I select more than one checkbox however, and try to echo $temp, I only see one selection that a person has made. any ideas - ideally I don't want to use JS. 
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Firstly, don't use the same ID for multiple elements, the ID should always be unique.

Comment: As for your question, I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add square brackets after checkbox name, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="a" class="selection">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="b" class="selection">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="c" class="selection">
```

This will pass checkboxes as array. Now you will get $this->input->post('checkbox') as something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => b [1] => c )
```