# How do i get the value from the select

Tags: php, html

How do i get the value from the select in to my mail?

---

php code

```
if (isset($_POST['voorletters']) && isset($_POST['achternaam']) && isset($_POST['geboortedatum'])
        && isset($_POST['email'])){
        $voorletters = $_POST['voorletters'];
        $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
        $geboortedatum = $_POST['geboortedatum'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $selectedOption = $_POST['pakketkeuze'];

        if (!empty($voorletters) && !empty($achternaam) && !empty($geboortedatum) && !empty($email)){

            $selectedPakketkeuze  = 'None';
            if(isset($_POST['pakketkeuze']) && is_array($_POST['pakketkeuze']) && count($_POST['pakketkeuze']) > 0){
                $selectedPakketkeuze = implode(', ', $_POST['pakketkeuze']);
            }

            $to = 'contact@pkschoonmaakdiensten.nl'; // Waar moet het naartoe?
            $sebject = 'Inschrijfing'; // Het onderwerp van het bericht

            $body = 'this is a test'."\n\n".'Voorletters: '.$voorletters."\n".'Achternaam: '.$achternaam."\n".'Pakketkeuze: '.$Pakketkeuze;

            $headers = 'From: '.$email;

            if (@mail($to, $sebject, $body, $headers)){
                echo 'the email send';
            }else{
                echo 'error sending email';
            }

        }else{
            echo 'er is iets niet ingevuld'; 
        }       
    }
```

---

html code

I need this value from this option, so when selected it will turn up in the mail when it will be sended.

```
<tr>
<td class="form-label"><h2>Abonnement keuze *</h2></td> 
<td>
    <span>
        <select name="pakketkeuze" class="selection-menu-inschrijfform">
            <option> --- </option>
            <option value="basic"> Basic</option>
            <option value="normaal"> Normaal</option>
            <option value="plus"> Plus</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</td>
```

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$body = 'this is a test'."\n\n".'Voorletters: '.$voorletters."\n".'Achternaam: '.$achternaam."\n".'Pakketkeuze: '.$Pakketkeuze;
```

to this:

```
$body = 'this is a test'."\n\n".'Voorletters: '.$voorletters."\n".'Achternaam: '.$achternaam."\n".'Pakketkeuze: '.$selectedOption;
```

Also, you can delete the following:

```
$selectedPakketkeuze  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['pakketkeuze']) && is_array($_POST['pakketkeuze']) && count($_POST['pakketkeuze']) > 0){
    $selectedPakketkeuze = implode(', ', $_POST['pakketkeuze']);
}
```

As `$_POST['pakketkeuze']` will not be an array unless you have multiple dropdowns called `pakketkeuze` in which case you need to add this inside your if to go with the change made before:

```
if(isset($_POST['pakketkeuze']) && is_array($_POST['pakketkeuze']) && count($_POST['pakketkeuze']) > 0){
    $selectedPakketkeuze = implode(', ', $_POST['pakketkeuze']);
    $selectedOption = $selectedPakketkeuze;
}
```

Comment: can u also tel me how to get a value out a few checkboxes with an array[] `<h2>Woensdag<input name="day[]" style="margin-left: 42px;" value="woensdag" type="checkbox"/></h2>`

Comment: [Have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes), it should help

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
$pakketKeuze = $_POST['pakketkeuze'];
```

If `basic` was selected wen the form was submitted, `$pakketKeuze` will contain the string `'basic'`

Answer (score 0):

You have used an undefined variable : $Pakketkeuze in email body variable. Instead, you may want to try the below code to get selected value of drop down box.

```
$body = 'this is a test'."\n\n".'Voorletters: '.$voorletters."\n".'Achternaam: '.$achternaam."\n".'Pakketkeuze: '.$_POST['pakketkeuze'];
```