# Send and receive state of unknown number of checkboxes through html form

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I have a MySql table and I would to be able to modify through a HTML form. The **MySql table** has columns like this:

```
id (int) | name (text) | option1 (boolean) | option2 (boolean)
```

The number of field `options` will grow over time and is not fixed, but always contains boolean data (0 or 1). The number of rows is not fixed as well.

I would like to modify the table with a **html form** which looks like this:

```html
<form action="file.php" method="post">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Option1</th>
    <th>Option2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lili</th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="lili_1"checked></th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="lili_2"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>thor</th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="thor_1" checked></th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="thor_2" checked></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>fred</th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="fred_1" checked></th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="fred_2" ></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Now it gets tricky. When I submit the form, on the server side **I don't know how many columns/lines there are**. I would like to update the whole database table (it's small), so **I need to know the state of every checkbox** for columns (option1, option2, ...) and rows (lili, thor, fred,...)

My idea is to **name each checkbox based on the column and value of field "name"**. I would also need to send an **array containing all the names and the columns** (because I can only know the boxes that were checked, not the unckecked ones).

On server-side, I then need to recreate the matrix with the array of columns and names and put 1 where a checkbox was checked (through the name of the checkbox).

**This seems to be a very error-prone and long to implement**... to do such an simple task. Can someone points me to a smarter way to to that ?

Thank you

Comment: Try `name="lili[]"` for the whole "lili" group and the same for all the rest of the groups. Server-side you'll get a list named "lili" (`$_POST['lili']`) with True/False values.

Comment: I submit the form with a html button <form action>

Comment: Are you sure ? Will I not get only "true" values ? As only the checkboxes actually checked will send data ?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. You need to also set `value="1/2/3/..."` on the checkboxes. Then you'll get a list of "id" instead of just `true` values so you can identify them.

Comment: Actually, there already is an answer for this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes

Comment: Thanks, it really helps. I will put name=lili[] and value=optionX depending on the column, like this I can directly know which column is targetted for each line. And I'll still need to send the array of names.

Answer (score 1):

You can group checkboxes with `name="thor[]"` or `name="lili[]"` in php backend you can retrieve it by `$_REQUEST['thor']`. Remember it is an array. So you loop it by `foreach($_REQUEST['thor'] as $thor){}` check value by `if($thor)`

Comment: I can't directly access $_REQUEST['thor'] because I don't know how many rows there are. I need to have a variable to know that. Thank you for your suggestion. I will also have an array with the names of the rows.

Comment: How can you render this html?

Comment: When I generate the html I have access to the db. I can see the number of columns and rows. When I receive the form, I don't know if new rows have been added, so I have to modify only the part of the table that was visible when I generated the html form. I'm very new to php/mysql, if you think I missed something obvious, that's very likely the case ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a bit of Javascript that will capture all of the field names and assign them to the value of a hidden field just before the form is submitted.  That will provide you with all of the info you need for server side processing.  Here is a **working sample**.

#### test.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test.php</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(){
          var element = $(this);
          var names = [];
          element.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i,o){
            names[names.length] = $(o).attr('name');
          });
          var value = names.join();
          var hidden = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'names').attr('value', value);
          element.append(hidden);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
      if(!empty($post_id)){
        $names = $_REQUEST['names'];
        $names = explode(',', $names);
        foreach($names as $name){
          $value = $_REQUEST[$name];
          if($value != "on") $value = "off";
          print "$name:$value<br/>";
        }
      }
    ?>
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo md5(date('Hms').session_id()); ?>" />
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Option1</th>
          <th>Option2</th>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>lili</th>
          <th><input type="checkbox" name="lili_1"></th>
          <th><input type="checkbox" name="lili_2"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>thor</th>
          <th><input type="checkbox" name="thor_1"></th>
          <th><input type="checkbox" name="thor_2"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>fred</th>
          <th><input type="checkbox" name="fred_1"></th>
          <th><input type="checkbox" name="fred_2"></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```