# How to add array to okhttp body (POST)

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Now i`m adding array as string to body:

```
RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
    .add("profiles", "[122, 125, 336]")
    .build();
```

But the server need array on post parameter. How can i add array instead of string? Is it posible with okhttp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are currently posting `profiles` as a string.  You will want to mimic a POST for a checkbox form field for `profiles`

```
RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
    .add("profiles[0]", "122")
    .add("profiles[1]", "125")
    .add("profiles[2]", "336")
    .build();
```

more info and good reading,

- https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-handle-multiple-checkboxes-values-in-a-form-using-php
- [Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4997252/794088)

Comment: What if the array is dynamic?

Comment: is the array is dynamic,  use a loop.

Comment: @BhavikMehta No. I'm not dumb, Arrays can also be immutable.  This answer shows the OP a simple way to send form values to their backend as an array called 'profiles'.  Please undo your down vote