# pass array or jsonobject to a php url with okhttp in android?

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, okhttp

I want to pass two values(can be array or jsonobject in curly braces only) to a php webservice by okhttp in android and it is like:

- userid="1" & productid={"1","2","3"}.

I know how to pass userid but I don't know how to pass productid values to url with the userid by okhttp.
If it is a duplicate kindly give me the link I have tried to search it but did not find any relevant answer.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/33307395/6848782 You can pass each element of array following this answer

Comment: you can convert that json object to string and then pass

Comment: @RogerRV  Thanks for replying....I have checked the post but It will post parms as productid1="1", productid2="2", productid3="3"...but I want all of them in a single parameter like productid={"1","2","3"} and this can be anything array, arraylist, hashmap, jsonobject...

Comment: @UdayNaidu can you elaborate your answer please...any code..

Comment: @ChiragGohil But if you added like key productid[0] and value 1 as the example you will receive it as an only variable in php. And if it's another type before passing you can transform your data into Array then make a loop to adding all elements in post in each array elements format

Comment: @ChiragGohil Try the answer I make

Answer (score 2):

```
    //Convert your object to an array
    FormBody.Builder formBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();
        for(int x=0; x<array.length; x++)
        {
            String val = (String) array[x];
            formBuilder.add("productid["+x+"]",val);
        } 
        RequestBody body = formBuilder.build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(YOUR_URL)
                .post(body)
                .build();
```

Note: if you want custom index not numeric arrays, in php arrays can be indexed by non-numeric index so you can loop any type of variable with a non-numeric index
 - Option 1 (with examples following the previus note):

```
FormBody.Builder formBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();
//Check if object is HashMap
if(object instanceof HashMap)
{
   for(Entry<String, String> e : m.entrySet()) {
      String key = e.getKey();
      String val = e.getValue();
      formBuilder.add("productid["+key+"]",val);
   }  
} else if(object instanceof Array) {
   for(int x=0; x<array.length; x++)
   {
      String val = (String) array[x];
      formBuilder.add("productid["+x+"]",val);
   }
}
RequestBody body = formBuilder.build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url(YOUR_URL)
.post(body)
.build();
```

- Option 2 (Bad practice for me)

Considering that you only want to pass only one param and .add() method only can pass String, you can convert all objects to an Array and then to String. String to 1 dimensional array:

```
<?php
 $productidstring = $_POST['productid'];
 $productid = StringToArray($productidstring);
 function StringToArray($productidstring)
 {
       $productidstringtmp = str_replace("[","",$productidstring);
       $productidstringtmp = str_replace("]","",$productidstring);
       $productidarray = explode(",",$productidstringtmp);
       return $productidarray;
 }
?>
```

Comment: @ChiragGohil Wait I will edit the answer I see that is incorrect

Comment: I tried this but does not work so let me know as you update the answer.

Comment: @ChiragGohil Sorry for that, now is updated.I'm new using okhttp I used others like volley

Comment: the code is working fine but still not solved my problem as I want only one variable and many values.... but thanks a lot for the help.If you find something more please post...Thanks once again...

Comment: @ChiragGohil Updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143635/discussion-between-roger-rv-and-chirag-gohil).