# How can i pass an array to okhttp android

Tags: android, okhttp

I want to pass an array as parameter in okhttp.I just tried like

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
.add("customerId", "0000000003")
.add("storeId","rayban") 
.add("items[]",array.toString())
.build();
```

I want to pass the items array to the form builder .
but i cant pass the array to the api.how can i do this.how to pass an array to okhttp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add array to okhttp body (POST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307395/how-to-add-array-to-okhttp-body-post)

Answer (score 1):

You can send like below

```
FormBody.Builder builder = new FormBody.Builder();
builder.add("customerId", "0000000003")
builder.add("storeId","rayban") 
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ 
  builder.add("items[" + i + "]", array[i])
}

FormBody body = builder.build();
```

Comment: @Jayanath can't resolve RequestBody.Builder  i mean the Builder