# Multiple checkbox to POST to another page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, checkbox

I have a list of checkbox (I need to give an id to each), then to make POST to another page

I have a while loop that which brings me one checkbox for each item in the database, I need to make each checkbox to make the POST, on the other page one check or X displays

**Edit page.php**

```
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
  echo "<td > <input type='checkbox' /> </td>}
```

**AnotherPage.php**

I guess I have to give an id to each checkbox to make the post and to get on another page.

[image: Image trying to explain that I need]

Comment: give `name` property to checkboxes, to get them in `POST`

Comment: but if I give it a name not all change when you post? I need to show only who was checked

Comment: Hi there. There are some helpful answers below, did any of them assist in your difficulty? If so, please consider upvoting any of them, and/or accepting one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of this question: [Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes)

See the checked answer there.

The main thing in PHP based applications is that a `form` element with a name with `name[]` (square brackets at the end) will result in an array in the receiving PHP script. That allows you to have all the values the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something like this

```
<form action="AnotherPage.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1">
</form>
```

And then in php

```
if (!empty($_POST['check1'])) {
// make your logic
}
```

Comment: OP is talking about **Multiple Checkbox**. This answer is for single checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
  <td> <input type='checkbox' name='CheckBoxName[]' value="<?echo $fila['GiveValueHere'];?>"/> </td>
}?>
```

**SomePage.php** (Submit Page)

```
<?

$totalCheckBoxChecked=sizeof($_POST['CheckBoxName']);

for($i=0;$i<$totalCheckBoxChecked;$i++)
{
    echo $checkBoxValue=$CheckBoxName[$i];
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```