# How to make PHP Contact form collect all selected checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, submit, contacts

This started off as a pre-built contact form that came bundled in an HTML template. All of the textbox field work perfectly fine when submitting the from. However I need some help with a checkbox section I added myself. I've been trying to do some research but can't get the script to include all the selected checkboxes in the e-mail.

Here's my working html:

```
<form class="nobottommargin" id="template-contactform" name="template-contactform" action="include/sendemail.php" method="post">

                                            <div class="form-process"></div>

                                            <div class="col_half">
                                                <label for="template-contactform-name">Name <small>*</small></label>
                                                <input type="text" id="template-contactform-name" name="template-contactform-name" value="" class="sm-form-control required" />
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col_half col_last">
                                                <label for="template-contactform-email">Email <small>*</small></label>
                                                <input type="email" id="template-contactform-email" name="template-contactform-email" value="" class="required email sm-form-control" />
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="clear"></div>

                                            <div class="col_half">
                                                <label for="template-contactform-phone">Phone <small>*</small></label>
                                                <input type="text" id="template-contactform-phone" name="template-contactform-phone" value="" class="sm-form-control required" />
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col_half col_last">
                                                <label for="template-contactform-budget">Budget</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="template-contactform-budget" name="template-contactform-budget" value="" class="sm-form-control" />
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="clear"></div>


                                            <div class="col_full">
                                               <label for="template-contactform-services[]">Services Required: </label>
                                                <input name="template-contactform-services[]" type="checkbox" value="Web-Design" />Web Design
                                                <input name="template-contactform-services[]" type="checkbox" value="E-Commerce" />E-Commerce
                                                <input name="template-contactform-services[]" type="checkbox" value="User-Experience" />User Experience
                                                <input name="template-contactform-services[]" type="checkbox" value="Branding" />Branding
                                                <input name="template-contactform-services[]" type="checkbox" value="Mobile-Design" />Mobile Design
                                                <input name="template-contactform-services[]" type="checkbox" value="Search-Marketing" />Search Marketing
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col_full">
                                                <label for="template-contactform-message">Deliverables &amp; Goals <small>*</small></label>
                                                <textarea class="required sm-form-control" id="template-contactform-message" name="template-contactform-message" rows="4" cols="30" placeholder="List the specific deliverables, services, and goals required..."></textarea>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col_full">
                                                <label for="template-contactform-missing">Anything Missing?</label>
                                                <textarea class="sm-form-control" id="template-contactform-missing" name="template-contactform-missing" rows="4" cols="30" placeholder="Is there anything else you think we should know?"></textarea>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col_full hidden">
                                                <input type="text" id="template-contactform-botcheck" name="template-contactform-botcheck" value="" class="sm-form-control" />
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col_full">

                                                <!--<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
                                                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your-recaptcha-site-key"></div>-->

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col_full">
                                                <button class="button button-3d nomargin" type="submit" id="template-contactform-submit" name="template-contactform-submit" value="submit">Send Message</button>
                                            </div>

                                        </form>
```

and here's my php:

```
    <?php

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$toemails = array();

$toemails[] = array(
            'email' => 'info@mydomain.com', // Your Email Address
            'name' => 'Your Name' // Your Name
        );

// Form Processing Messages
$message_success = 'We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your Message and will get Back to you as soon as possible.';

// Add this only if you use reCaptcha with your Contact Forms
$recaptcha_secret = 'your-recaptcha-secret-key'; // Your reCaptcha Secret

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// If you intend you use SMTP, add your SMTP Code after this Line


if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
if( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] != '' ) {

    $name = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-name'] : '';
    $email = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-email'] : '';
    $phone = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] : '';
    $budget = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-budget'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-budget'] : '';
    $service = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-services'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-services'] : '';
    $message = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-message'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-message'] : '';
    $missing = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-missing'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-missing'] : '';


    $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message From Contact Form';

    $botcheck = $_POST['template-contactform-botcheck'];

    if( $botcheck == '' ) {

        $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
        $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
        foreach( $toemails as $toemail ) {
            $mail->AddAddress( $toemail['email'] , $toemail['name'] );
        }
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
        $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
        $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
        $budget = isset($budget) ? "Budget: $budget<br><br>" : '';
        $service = isset($service) ? "Services Required: $service<br><br>" : '';
        $message = isset($message) ? "Deliverables & Goals: $message<br><br>" : '';
        $missing = isset($missing) ? "Anything Missing: $missing<br><br>" : '';

        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

        $body = "$name $email $phone $budget $service $message $missing $referrer";

        // Runs only when File Field is present in the Contact Form
        if ( isset( $_FILES['template-contactform-file'] ) && $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['name'] );
        }

        // Runs only when reCaptcha is present in the Contact Form
        if( isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
            $recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            $response = file_get_contents( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $recaptcha_secret . "&response=" . $recaptcha_response );

            $g_response = json_decode( $response );

            if ( $g_response->success !== true ) {
                echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Captcha not Validated! Please Try Again." }';
                die;
            }
        }

        $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
        $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

        if( $sendEmail == true ):
            echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message_success . '" }';
        else:
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
        endif;
    } else {
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!" }';
    }
} else {
    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Please <strong>Fill up</strong> all the Fields and Try Again." }';
}
} else {
echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later." }';
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to give different `name` attributes to the `<input type="checkbox" />` tag. Then you can check whether a checkbox is checked with the `isset()` function.

Comment: Thanks, i see how that can work, but how can i get it to be like an array, where my email template would say services required: web, graphic, etc.

Comment: this mail help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes

Comment: As a complete php noob not really :( I need to know exactly how to modify my existing script. I've seen some stuff using implode and is_array instead of isset but can't make much sense of it and I keep breaking my form lol