# How to get Multiple Values from a foreach loop generated Checkboxes

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to get multiple values from a foreach loop generated check boxes. Please check my codes below and give me some suggestion. Thanks.

View file

```
<?php foreach ($size_list as $size) { ?>
<label><input name="size_id" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $size->size_id;?>" />
<?php echo $v_size_list->size;?></label>
<?php } ?>
```

When i submit this form after selecting multiple checkboxes, i got only the last check box value. But i want all selected check box values. Please give me some suggestion. Thanks

Comment: use array like this name="size_id[]"

Answer (score 1):

use array in name like

```
name="size_id[]"
```

and you will get all selected checkbox value in array.

Comment: Thanks. It works. i got the value and then i use implode function in controller to separate the values. :)

Answer (score 1):

use change your checkbox name into array and it contation all the checkbox value in array structure which you checked in form

**`name="size_id[ ]"`**

```
<?php foreach ($size_list as $size) { ?>

<label><input name="size_id[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $size->size_id;?>" />
<?php echo $v_size_list->size;?></label>
```

and get the value by

**`print_r($_POST['size_id']);`**

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to check this answer:
[Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes)

So your checkboxes name have to be size_id[], and in the controller, where you check the value of the checkbox, you have to loop this with a foreach.

```
public function posted()
{
    $checkboxes = $this->input->post("size_id");
    foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox)
    {
        // in this loop you can check the value of the selected checkbox
    }
}
```