# Get value from checkbox array through filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'check_list')

Tags: php, html

My HTML code following:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 3">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 4">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 5">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and my PHP code test.php

```
$check_list = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'check_list');
var_dump($check_list);
```

php code mention top return false,
but if i am use : `$check_list = $_POST['check_list']` then its work fine. how can i solve my code through `filter_input`

Comment: `'check_list'` would need to be `$_POST['check_list']`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes?rq=1

Comment: i need it through filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'check_list');

Comment: filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'checkbox_name', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY)

Answer (score -2):

Try
    filter_input_array
instead, [see ref](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php#88478 is what you need to do for anyone who ends up here and want help

Comment: filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'checkbox_name', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY)