# I can get the Multiple selection to work for the sports field

Tags: php, html

I am trying to process a form through POST method and i am having trouble with passing multiple selection field.

```
<label for="sport">Favourite sport: </label>
    <select id="sport" name="favsport[]" size="4" multiple>
        <option value="soccer">Soccer</option>
        <option value="cricket">Cricket</option>
        <option value="squash">Squash</option>
        <option value="golf">Golf</option>
        <option value="tennis">Tennis</option>
        <option value="basketball">Basketball</option>
        <option value="baseball">Baseball</option>
    </select>





$sportstr = $_POST["favsport"];
<p><strong> Favourite Sport = </strong> <?php echo "$sportstr"; ?></p>
```

Comment: `print_r($sportstr);` will reveal you are trying to echo an array...maybe a loop or an `implode()` is in order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get $\_POST from multiple checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post the form with the multiple selection field `favsport[]` it is posted as an array:

```
array (
  'favsport' => 
  array (
    0 => 'cricket',
    1 => 'squash',
    2 => 'golf',
    3 => 'tennis',
    4 => 'basketball',
    5 => 'baseball',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your field name is `favsport[]` and it give you array in php `$_POST["favsport"]` you are doing echo `$sportstr` variable it will give you **Notice: Array to string conversion** thats why you have to use  `print_r()` function to print array. use below code it might be your solution.

```
$sportstr = $_POST["favsport"];
print_r($sportstr);
```

Comment: This is what i am getting

Comment: The following information was received from the user:

name = Raveel

Email = rav123

Post Address = 8 street

print_r($sportstr); //
Favourite Sport = Array

Email List = Yes

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with `multiselect dropdown`, then you can get its value like:

```
$sportstr = $_POST["favsport"];
```

here `$sportstr` is an array, so you have to use `foreach()` to access its all elements.