# PHP keep checkbox checked after submitting POST form

Tags: php, checkbox

How can I keep checkbox checked after submitting a form?
I tried using this method:

```
<input type = "checkbox" name="math[]" value="Addition" <?php if(isset($_POST['math'])) echo "checked='checked'";?>/>Addition<br>
```

but all of my checkbox will keep checked even if I only select one, here is my code:

```
<form id="calc" action="calculator.php" method="POST" >
<b>Enter First No:  <br>    
<input type = "text" name="num1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['num1'])){echo $num1;} ?>" required="required"/><br>
Enter Second No: <br>
<input type = "text" name="num2" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['num2'])){echo $num2;} ?>" required="required"/><br>
<b>Select Operation: <br>
<input type = "checkbox" name="math[]" value="Addition" <?php if(isset($_POST['math'])) echo "checked='checked'";?>/>Addition<br>
<input type = "checkbox" name="math[]" value="Subtraction" <?php if(isset($_POST['math'])) echo "checked='checked'";?>/>Subtraction<br>
<input type ="submit" value="compute" name="btnsubmit"> <br>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post and put your html in html or code block

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to put it in the bracket,,,, Im new to this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get $\_POST from multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes)

Comment: try change required="required" to required

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez It does not change anything

Comment: You should check for if(isset($_POST['math'][0])), cause you'r dealing with multi dimension array

Comment: @B.Mossavari ok I'll try

Comment: @B.Mossavari dude it doesn't work

Comment: fist checkbox should be if(isset($_POST['math'][0])) and secound should be if(isset($_POST['math'][1])) and so on ...

Comment: @B.Mossavari yeah I did that already,

Answer (score 1):

change :

```
<form id="calc" action="calculator.php" method="POST" >
<b>Enter First No:  <br>    
<input type = "text" name="num1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['num1'])){echo $num1;} ?>" required="required"/><br>
Enter Second No: <br>
<input type = "text" name="num2" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['num2'])){echo $num2;} ?>" required="required"/><br>
<b>Select Operation: <br>
<input type = "checkbox" name="math[]" value="Addition" <?php if(isset($_POST['math'])) echo "checked='checked'";?>/>Addition<br>
<input type = "checkbox" name="math[]" value="Subtraction" <?php if(isset($_POST['math'])) echo "checked='checked'";?>/>Subtraction<br>
<input type ="submit" value="compute" name="btnsubmit"> <br>
```

To :

```
<form id="calc" action="" method="POST" >
<b>Enter First No:  <br>    
<input type = "text" name="num1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['num1'])){echo $_POST['num1'];} ?>" required="required"/><br>
Enter Second No: <br>
<input type = "text" name="num2" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['num2'])){echo $_POST['num2'];} ?>" required="required"/><br>
<b>Select Operation: <br>
<input type = "checkbox" name="math[]" value="Addition" 
  <?php if(isset($_POST['math'][0]))
  { 
    if($_POST['math'][0]=="Addition"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}
  } ?> />Addition<br>
<input type = "checkbox" name="math[]" value="Subtraction"
  <?php if(isset($_POST['math'][0]) || isset($_POST['math'][1])) 
  {
    if($_POST['math'][0]=="Subtraction"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}
    if(isset($_POST['math'][1])){
      if($_POST['math'][1]=="Subtraction"){ 
        echo 'checked="checked"';
      }
    }
  } ?> />Subtraction<br>

<input type ="submit" value="compute" name="btnsubmit"> <br>
```

Comment: Dude, thank you very much. God Bless you and your family <3

Comment: Welcome.. Up vote and accept answer. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this now and wanted to add to the answer by bharat parmer. Instead of checking each array element individually, I used the following as my PHP section:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['math']) && in_array("Addition", $_POST['math']))
                echo 'checked="checked"';?>
```

That seemed more direct, especially when the array could be large.