# inserting multiple records in one row using single checkbox with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have confusion in inserting multiple records in one row using single checkbox with php mysql

This is my form table

```
<form action="tambahMatkul.php" method="post" id="ambil_matkul">  
        <table class="tabel table-bordered table-stripped table-responsive">

        <tr>
        <th width="5%">cek</th>
        <th width="19%">Kode</th>
        <th width="19%">Mata Kuliah</th>
        <th width="19%">W/P</th>
        <th width="19%">SKS</th>
        <th width="19%">Kelas</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            include "koneksi.php";

            $query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM matakuliah")or die(mysqli_error($connect));
            while($mahasiswa = $query->fetch_array())
            {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="cek[]" value="<?php echo $mahasiswa['kodeMatkul'] ?>"> 
                         <
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $mahasiswa['kodeMatkul']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mahasiswa['namaMatkul']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mahasiswa['pilihan']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mahasiswa['sks']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mahasiswa['kelas']; ?></td>
                    </input>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
        <hr/>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Tambah</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is my form action

```
<?php

$codes = $_POST['cek'];

foreach($codes as $code)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","krs");
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO krs VALUES(NULL, '161402133', '{$code}')");
}
if($query)
echo "Matakuliah sudah ditambahkan.";
```

i don't know what to do? still beginner . please help me master

Comment: there is a random floating `<` in the above code

Comment: What are the column names into which you are trying to insert these multiple values? Or is it one column and you are trying to insert a concatenated string?

Comment: Can you show the table schema, and explain how the checkboxes relate to the values that should be inserted?

Comment: Also, see about parametrised queries

Comment: yes actually my database is still a  mess. I'm trying to  make insert like "by only checking one box then all the other columns's values that are in the same  row will be inserted in my database"

Comment: the random floating< is a typo sory...

Comment: tabel matakuliah (  kode_matkuL 
 2 nama_matkul 
 3 semester 
 4 tahun
 5 pilihan 
 6 sks

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop and array to get multiple checkbox values. Below are the example

```
 $a=array();
 foreach($_POST['cek'] as $value) {
        $a[]=$value;
 }
```

also i am going to reference [This POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes) for more details

Post Author name:[sean-walsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603502/sean-walsh)

Some more thing are wrong in your code:

1: Remove Database connection in loop

I recommend this code to insert these values into Database

```
$a=array();
     foreach($_POST['cek'] as $value) {
            $a[]=$value;
     }
$checkData = implode(",", $a);
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","krs");
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO krs VALUES(NULL, '161402133', ".$checkData.")");

 mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Two problems: 1) Unless they check all the boxes, there won't be enough values in `$a`, since only checked boxes are in `$_POST['cek']`. 2) You have an extra `,` at the end of the values.

Comment: @Barmar thanks your response. but when form submit only `checked` check box value pass.. please read this article  https://www.formget.com/php-checkbox/

Comment: @Barmar. you are right `,` extra at the end of string.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for correction. i have update my answer

Comment: I know only the checked boxes are passed. That's the problem.

Comment: Did you forget to put quotes around `$checkData`?

Comment: @Barmar i have update my answer, i know some time without concatenation errors occur. but in this case without concatenation it's work. check this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fbaf0feefa722a96b69e2abfda905e5ef4e03974

Comment: It's still the same problem. You will have different numbers of values depending on how many boxes are checked. But the query has to insert the same number of values as there are table columns.

Comment: We really need an answer to the question I posted in the comments above before we can give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the POST values and them save in one query.

For example:

```
$const = 161402133;
$values = "('{$const}'," . implode("),('{$const}',", $_POST['cek']) . ")";

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "krs");
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO krs VALUES {$values}");

if ($query) {
            echo "Matakuliah sudah ditambahkan.";
}
```

Comment: This can't be right. The number of `$_POST['cek']` values will depend on the number of boxes that are checked, but your query requires there to be values for every column in the table.

Comment: `$_POST['cek']` contains only checked checkboxes.

Comment: That's the problem I was pointing out. `$values` will have a different number of values depending on which checkboxes are checked, but the query requires there to be enough values to fill in every column of the table.

Comment: Never mind, I misread your code. You're creating multiple rows, not multiple columns in the same row.

Comment: But the question says "multiple records in one row". He probably needs to normalize his schema for this to be the right answer. I suspect he's actually using a single column with a comma-separated list.

Comment: We really need an answer to the question I posted in the comments above before we can give a proper answer.

Comment: i thought i could insert all these one row values :") not just the checked one bsc of while function...

Answer (score 0):

`input` tag doesn't have close tag.

My code for your problem is below

**HTML**

```
<form action="tambahMatkul.php" method="post" id="ambil_matkul">  
    <table class="tabel table-bordered table-stripped table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <th width="5%">cek</th>
            <th width="19%">Kode</th>
            <th width="19%">Mata Kuliah</th>
            <th width="19%">W/P</th>
            <th width="19%">SKS</th>
            <th width="19%">Kelas</th>
        </tr>
        <?php include "koneksi.php";
        $query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM matakuliah")or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        while($mahasiswa = $query->fetch_array()){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cek[]" value="<?php echo $mahasiswa['kodeMatkul'] ?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $mahasiswa['kodeMatkul']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mahasiswa['namaMatkul']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mahasiswa['pilihan']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mahasiswa['sks']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mahasiswa['kelas']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <hr/>
    <div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Tambah</button></div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $value = '';
    foreach($_POST['cek'] as $code) $value .= '(NULL, "161402133", "{$code}"),';// this loop add each value of $_POST['cek'] into $value as format reacquired for insert. 
    //echo $value;
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","krs");
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, 'INSERT INTO krs VALUES'.rtrim($value,',').';'); //rtrim($value,',') removes the last occurrence of comma (,)
    if($query)echo "Matakuliah sudah ditambahkan.";
?>
```