# What does $_POST['sometext'] == 'on' mean in PHP

Tags: php, post

I learn PHP and in one of examples I found a part of a code I don't understand.

```
....
if (array_key_exists('submited', $_POST)) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['counter']; $i++) {
            if (!empty($_POST['checkeditem' . $i]))
                if ($_POST['checkeditem' . $i] == 'on') {
                    $rezultat = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM gas WHERE id=" . $i);
                    echo "Checked items are deleted";
                }
        }
    } else {
....
```

In the code above I don't understand this code line:

```
$_POST['checkeditem' . $i] == 'on'
```

There is no attribute with the name='on' in entire code, so it is not related to any name attribute. What is value 'on' and is there other values like that one, that are related to $_POST? Could you suggest me what to google, to find more about this? Thank you.

Comment: It's comparing the value of the checked item. Check your form for value.

Comment: There is no 'on' value. It is a counter for checkboxes.

Comment: Somewhere in your form are things like `<input type="checkbox" name="checkeditem1" value="on">`.  But this is not good code or a good way to go about what it is doing.

Comment: This is input field:
<input type='checkbox' name='checkeditem" . $niz['id'] . "'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the code above I don't understand this code line** and here `on` seems checkbox is checked or not?

```
$_POST['checkeditem' . $i] == 'on'
```

will compare like

```
$_POST['checkeditem1'] == 'on'

$_POST['checkeditem2'] == 'on'
```

till the last iteration of the loop e.g 100th

```
$_POST['checkeditem100'] == 'on'
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I change 'on' with some other string, for example 'checkeditem' or it must be 'on'?

Comment: it depends on your checkbox value. Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes